# how to set Tortoise svn-property for a folder to apply to all new files inside

Tags: svn, version-control, properties, tortoisesvn

Usually we need to set following properties to files which we commit in our repository using Tortoise subversion

```
svn:eol-style as native
svn:executable as ON
```

but whenever I `commit` a **new** file to repository I need to **re-set** the properties. Is it a way to set these **permanently** so that I don't need to repeat the process post every check-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto),

> Whenever you introduce a file to version control using the svn add or
>   svn import commands, Subversion tries to assist by setting some common
>   file properties automatically.

If you want to do something over and above that, you would need to configure your subversion server [suitably](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config) - essentially edit the subversion `config` file and update the `auto-props` section.

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a subversion client and can only do so much.

Answer (score 1):

**Credit to Raghuram for the hint of the answer** (and that's why I accepted his answer)

Even `TortoiseSVN` provides a way to set such a property

```
tsvn:autoprops
```

As quoted [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html)

Subversion allows you to set **autoprops** which will be applied to newly added or imported files, based on the file extension. This depends on every client having set appropriate autoprops in their subversion configuration file. `tsvn:autoprops` can be set on folders and these will be merged with the user's local autoprops when importing or adding files. The format is the same as for subversion `autoprops`, e.g.

```
*.sh = svn:eol-style=native;svn:executable
```

sets two properties on files with the .sh extension.

Comment: Note, that this isn't foolproof. It will only work for users using Tortoise, not a commandline client. It also won't work if you add a folder in repo-browser. http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-auto-props